# Java revalidate(); moves Objects that have been re-positioned, back to the original location

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel, layout-manager

I'm making an application in which JLabels are created and can be re-positioned using

```
.setLocation(x,y)
```

However, whenever I invoke

```
.setVisible(true)
```

the JLabels move back to their original position. I think it has something to do with

`.setVisible()`'s   ---  `revalidate()` function

But I am unsure of how to override or avoid `revalidate()` effects.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You don't override or change `revalidate()` -- rather you use the appropriate layout manager since all revalidate does is to tell the layout managers to layout the components held by this and all nested containers. One "solution" is to use a `null` layout, but I strongly advise against that as this will lead to hard to debug and maintain GUI's, ones that might look good on one platform and terrible on all others. Consider nesting JPanels, each using its own layout manager, and using Borders, such as an EmptyBorder, to achieve your desired GUI layout.

Answer (score 0):

If your program (not the user) is setting the location of the components then don't do this. Instead use the appropriate layout manager, or combination of nested panels with different layout managers to achieve your layout.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

> JLabels are created and can be re-positioned using setLocation(x,y)

However, if you are creating an application that allows the users to drag components around the screen then you need to use a null layout so you can control the location (and the size) of each component.

However, I would recommend you take at look at [Drag Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/). This is a layout manager that implements most of the layout manager functionality, but will allow you to control the location of the component.

> However, whenever I invoke setVisible(true)

Also, Swing components are visible by default so there is no need to invoke that method, except on top level containers (JFrame, JDialog etc).